# Check if knockoutjs is loaded

Tags: knockout.js, cdn

I wish to provide a backup for loading knockoutjs from a CDN, what object is best to check if it's loaded?

If I were to use something like this for jQuery.

What would it be for knockoutjs?

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Fallback to loading jQuery from a local path if the CDN is unavailable
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>'));
</script>
```

I'm guessing it's ko?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In testing by disabling my network card, checking for ko is sufficient.

A simple question with a simple answer, but handy so other people don't need to bother checking.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.0.js" ></script>
<script>
   // Fallback to loading knockout locally if the CDN is unavailable
   (window.ko || document.write("<script src='/yourpath/knockout-2.2.0.js'><\/script>"));
</script>
```